# How to speed up awk command in linux?

Tags: linux, awk, time, timezone, utc

I am using awk command in linux to convert utc to localtime, but the file size is huge (>30 gb) and it would cost more than an hour.

Here is my code:

```
awk -F"," '{cmd="date -d \"$(date -d \""$1"\")-4hours\" \"+%Y%m%d_%H\"";cmd | getline datum; close(cmd); print $0 ","datum""}' data.txt
```

How can I speed up this command or is there any simple way to do this conversion in linux?

```
Here is the sample of input:

utc,id
2018-03-31 16:00:49.425,4485
2018-04-1 17:01:19.425,30019
2018-05-31 18:01:49.425,15427
2018-08-20 19:01:55.425,17579
2018-09-2 20:02:31.425,23716
2018-10-15 21:03:34.425,24772

expected output:

utc,id,localtime
2018-03-31 16:00:49.425,4485,20180331_12
2018-04-1 17:01:19.425,30019,20180401_13
2018-05-31 18:01:49.425,15427,20180531_14
2018-08-20 19:01:55.425,17579,20180820_15
2018-09-2 20:02:31.425,23716,20180902_16
2018-10-15 21:03:34.425,24772,20181015_17
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please post sample of input and expected output and let us know then.

Comment: How does your date-format look like in field 1? (how does your input file look like)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason why your original solution is slow is due to the system call to `date`. Each record/line you process with awk calls an external command to perform the date-conversion. Such an external call needs to be loaded into memory, executed and its output needs to be processed by awk. We can speed this up if we can do the actual date-conversion in awk itself.

---

**general comment:** when you convert dates and times from UTC to your local timezone, you have to take into account that January 1 is in a different timezone than August 1. This is due to daylight-saving time. The algorithm below does not provide a solution to that as the OP just requested a shift of 4h, or a shift to his current time-zone. (*remark:* the solution for gawk 4.1.2 or newer will take DST into account)

---

Below I present several solutions which you can use depending on which awk you use:

**Gnu awk:** One of the various extensions of `gawk` are Time-functions. The two useful time-functions for this problem are `mktime` and `strftime`:

> - **`mktime(datespec,[utc-flag])`**: This converts a date specification string, `datespec`, of the form `YYYY MM DD hh mm ss` into a Unix epoch time, i.e. the total seconds since 1970 01 01 UTC. Since gawk-4.2.1 you can use the `utc-flag` to indicate `datespec` is in UTC or not. Prior to gawk-4.2.1 it assumed the local time-zone.
> - **`strftime(format,timestamp,[utc-flag])`**: This converts an epoch-time `timestamp` into a formatted string (same formatting as the `date` command). You can use the `utc-flag` the indicate that the returned time should be in UTC or in the local time-zone.
>
> More info in the [GNU awk manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Time-Functions)

We want to convert field 1 from UTC to local time-zone. Since we do not know the format of field 1, we assume the existence of a function `convert_time(str)` which formats `str` into the format `YYYY MM DD hh mm ss` that can be accepted by `mktime`:

*gawk 4.1.2 or newer:*

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}
      { # convert $1 into YYYY MM DD hh mm ss
        datestring=convert_time($1)
        # convert datestring (as UTC) into epoch 
        datum=mktime(datestring,1)
        # convert epoch into string (local TZ)
        datum=strftime("\042%Y%m%d_%H\042",datum)
        # print and append
        print $0,datum
      }' data.txt
```

*prior to gawk 4.1.2:* Here we cannot make use of the `utc-flag`, so we force awk to work in UTC:

```
$ TZ=UTC awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}
             { # convert $1 into YYYY MM DD hh mm ss
               datestring=convert_time($1)
               # convert datestring (as UTC) into epoch 
               datum=mktime(datestring)
               # perform TZ correction
               datum-=4*3600;
               # convert epoch into string (local TZ)
               datum=strftime("\042%Y%m%d_%H\042",datum)
               # print and append
               print $0,datum
              }' data.txt
```

**POSIX awk:** if you do not have GNU awk, but any other awk, you cannot use those time-functions as they are GNU awk specific. It is however possible to implement them:

```
awk '

# Algorithm from "Astronomical Algorithms" By J.Meeus
function mktime_posix(datestring,    a,t) {
    split(datestring,a," ")
    if (a[1] < 1970) return -1
    if (a[2] <= 2) { a[1]--; a[2]+=12 }
    t=int(a[1]/100); t=2-t+int(t/4)
    t=int(365.25*a[1]) + int(30.6001*(a[2]+1)) + a[3] + t - 719593
    return t*86400 + a[4]*3600 + a[5]*60 + a[6]
}

function strftime_posix(epoch, JD,yyyy,mm,dd,HH,MM,SS,A,B,C,D,E ) {
    if (epoch < 0 ) return "0000 00 00 00 00 00.000000"
    JD=epoch; SS=JD%60; JD-=SS; JD/=60; MM=JD%60;
    JD-=MM; JD/=60; HH=JD%24; JD-=HH; JD/=24;
    JD+=2440588
    A=int((JD - 1867216.25)/(36524.25))
    A=JD+1+A-int(A/4)
    B=A+1524; C=int((B-122.1)/365.25); D=int(365.25*C); E=int((B-D)/30.6001)
    dd=B-D-int(30.6001*E)
    mm = E < 14 ? E-1 : E - 13
    yyyy=mm>2?C-4716:C-4715
    return sprintf("\042%0.4d-%0.2d-%0.2d %0.2d:%0.2d:%06.3f",yyyy,mm,dd,HH,MM,SS)
}

{ # convert $1 into YYYY MM DD hh mm ss
  datestring=convert_time($1)
  # convert datestring (as UTC) into epoch 
  datum=mktime_posix(datestring)
  # perform TZ correction
  datum-=4*3600;
  # convert epoch into string (local TZ)
  datum=strftime_posix(datum)
  # print and append
  print $0,datum
}' data.txt
```

Comment: Just a heads up: my Debian (Stretch, 9.9) offers gawk 4.1.4 which apparently won't support that utc-flag: `2 is invalid as number of arguments for mktime`.

Comment: True, this is only part of gawk 4.2 and beyond.