# Awk exctracting column but just from one row

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I have a script in the following form:

```
2017-12-11 10:20:16.993 ...

2017-12-12 10:19:16.993 ...

2017-12-13 10:17:16.993 ...
```

and I want to extract the first column via `awk - F.` , and compare it to actual system time in seconds and print the line if the difference is less than 300 seconds.

```
>   SYSTEM_TIME=$(date +%s)
>                 awk -F. -v system_time=$SYSTEM_TIME '{gsub(/[-:]/," ",$1); if(system_time-mktime($1) <= 300) {print $0}}' log.txt
```

This is my code, but I can't use mktime because it's not in the POSIX norm. Can it be done without it?

Thanks,

Ahmed

Answer (score 3):

> **General Remark:** logfiles are often incomplete. A date-time format is given, but often the time-zone is missing. When daylight-saving comes into-play it can mess up your complete karma if you are missing your timezone.

---

**Note:** In all commands below, it will be assumed that the date in the logfile is in UTC and that the system runs in UTC. If this is not the case, be aware that daylight saving time will create problems when running any of the commands below arround the time daylight-saving kicks in.

---

**Combination of `date` and `awk`:** (not POSIX)

If your `date` command has the `-d` flag (not POSIX), you can run the following:

```
awk -v r="(date -d '300 seconds ago' '+%F %T.%3N)" '(r < $0)'
```

**GNU awk only:**

If you want to make use of `mktime`, it is then easier to just do:

```
awk 'BEGIN{s=systime();FS=OFS="."}
     {t=$1;gsub(/[-:]/," ",t); t=mktime(t)}
     (t-s < 300)' logfile
```

I will be under the assumption that the log-files are not created in the future, so all times are always smaller than system time.

**POSIX:**

If you cannot make use of `mktime` but want to use posix only, which also implies that `date` does not have the `-d` flag, you can create your own implementation of `mktime`. Be aware, that the version presented here does not do any timezone corrections as is done with `mktime`. `mktime_posix` assumes that the `datestring` is in UTC

```
awk -v s="$(date +%s)" '
# Algorithm from "Astronomical Algorithms" By J.Meeus
function mktime_posix(datestring,    a,t) {
    split(datestring,a," ")
    if (a[1] < 1970) return -1
    if (a[2] <= 2) { a[1]--; a[2]+=12 }
    t=int(a[1]/100); t=2-t+int(t/4)
    t=int(365.25*a[1]) + int(30.6001*(a[2]+1)) + a[3] + t - 719593
    return t*86400 + a[4]*3600 + a[5]*60 + a[6]
}
BEGIN{FS=OFS="."}
{t=$1;gsub(/[-:]/," ",t); t=mktime_posix(t)}
(t-s <= 300)' logfile
```

Related: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56236172/8344060), [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59611409/8344060)

Comment: But I can't use mktime.

Comment: I get very different values when I run `mktime()` and `mktime_posix()` on the same timestamps. The `mktime()` values agree with `date +%s -d` values. Looks like it's a locale issue as they''re off by 6 hours and my TZ is 6 hours behind GMT.

Comment: @EdMorton `mktime_posix` assumes that the TZ is UTC. `mktime` does a timezone correction. You can try to run it with `TZ=UTC awk '...'`

Comment: Yeah, that'll do it. Maybe just add that to your answer?

Comment: Do you have an eample of a timestamp that'd create a problem? I tried the second before, at, and after DST started ended in my TZ and had no problem but I assume there is one sometime... I'm interested in this solution since if it works robustly it'd solve a common problem without the usual performance hit.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206727/discussion-between-kvantour-and-ed-morton).

Comment: So... I think the potential problem you mention is that if your machine runs on non-UTC and uses those non-UTC timestamps when logging then your log files can contain timestamps that span a DST start time. The difference at that day/time between 01:59:59 and 03:00:01 should be 2 seconds since 2am is when the clocks jump forward to 3am and using `date` or `mktime` will produce that output but `mktime_posix` will output a difference of 3602 seconds (1 hour and 2 seconds) instead since mktime_posix doesn't know about DST since it's not locale-aware. Right?

Comment: @EdMorton Correct, `mktime_epoch` has only knowledge of a single time-zone and hence no DST (I'm refering to UTC+n, and not Europe/London as TZ). If your timezone is set to be any of the forms `Europe/London` and not `UTC+n` or `CEST`, then they both will behave as described by you. **But**, `mktime` as aditive. Where `date` will claim that `02:00;00` does not exist, `mktime` will convert it. You can see that mktime on `02:00:00` and `03:00:00` give equal results. (Use `zdump -v Brussels/London -c 2019,2020` to play.

Comment: Example: `TZ=Europe/London awk 'BEGIN{print mktime("2019 3 31 0 59 59"), mktime("2019 3 31 1 0 0"), mktime("2019 3 31 2 0 0")}'` returns `1553993999 1553994000 1553994000`. You notice that the last two cases have an identical result. When you use a TZ without DST, the game is different: `TZ=GMT awk 'BEGIN{print mktime("2019 3 31 0 59 59"), mktime("2019 3 31 1 0 0"), mktime("2019 3 31 2 0 0")}'` returns `1553993999 1553994000 1553997600`

Comment: The first case (date + awk) will fail when switching from 03 to 02 by DST because the sorting order is broken.

Answer (score 0):

I can think in doing this as its shorter.

```
#!/bin/bash

SYSTEM_TIME=$(date +%s)
LOGTIME=$( date "+%s" -d "$( awk -F'.'  '{print $1}' <( head -1 inputtime.txt ))" )
DIFFERENCEINSECONDS=$( echo "$SYSTEM_TIME $LOGTIME" | awk '{ print ($1 - $2)}' )

if [[ "$DIFFERENCEINSECONDS" -gt 300 ]]
then
    echo "TRIGGERED!"
fi
```

Hope its useful for you. Let me know.

Note : I assumed your input log could be called *inputtime.txt*. You need to change for your actual filename of course.